# How to allow Android Market License Check through a secured network?

Tags: google-play-store, drm

We have a secure network that doesn't allow internet access. Unfortunately one app from the Android Market we purchased for our honeycomb tablets uses Market License Check to verify that we've purchased the app on, what it seems like, a daily basis. What site(s) do we have need to allow access to for this authentication to happen?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any info on this.  If you don't get a definite answer I would try allowing android.com and subdomains.

Comment: That might be tricky as we want to block users from using the android market.

Comment: [This](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1056433) could help with blocking it on devices.  Assuming the licence server is part of market.android.com, you'd need the specific ports used as well.  [This](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) could be used to sniff the traffic and determine the info you need.

Comment: BTW, the first link only applies to paid Google Apps accounts not locking down a tablet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "android.clients.google.com" with port 5228 (TCP).

Comment: Awesome! How'd you find it?

Comment: tablet IP address trace

Comment: And you can still block users from the Market too?  Impressive find!

Comment: Opening the port above also allows the market app to download software so to prevent that we are removing the market app from the tablets.